# Angular 10 Added Object Property Does Appear In Cart

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I'm trying to add a json object property to an endpoint which is cart + id based on user input which is clicking on a radio button. Basically the user wants to add an item to a shopping cart, but they must first choose a size by clicking on a radio button s, m or large.

The item is added to cart from the product object which I don't have a size s, m or large but have "size:" "", this way I felt O would be able to change it to the actual size chosen by the user.

I am grabbing the value size from the component and pass it to the service. When adding to the shopping cart I do a post which I have on other items and it works, but with the add to cart I want to add the size so I handle this a bit different than just a regular post. What I don't understand is when I click add to cart and go to the development tool console is shows the post and the size.  But what I don't understand is that it does not add the size in to the actual object (cart)when I go to the db.json  file which is a fake back end.  I have done a lot of research for this but can't get it to work. Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.  I would so grateful.

Code snippet included.

Model

```
import { Product } from './product';


export class CartItem {

    static splice(arg0: number) {
      throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }

    id: number;
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    qty: number;
    price: number;
    size?:string;
    imageUrl:string;

    constructor(id:number, size:string,  product:Product, qty= 1) {

        this.id = id;
        this.productId = product.id;
        this.price = product.price;
        this.size = size;
        this.productName = product.name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
         
        
    }


    
}
```

Product Item Component

```
 onSubmit() {

   this.submitted = true;
  
   // reset alerts on submit
   this.alertService.clear();

   // stop here if form is invalid

   if (this.form.invalid) {
     return;
   } 

   if (!this.form.invalid){
      this.Valuesize = this.form.value.sizeBy
   
    this.handleAddToCart();
     }
  
  }

 
  handleAddToCart(){
    this.Valuesize;
    alert("Am I able to to get Valuesize" + this.Valuesize)
     this.cartService.addProductToCart(this.productItem,this.Valuesize).subscribe((product:Product) =>{
      this.productItem = product;
       this.msg.sendMsg(this.productItem)
  })
}
```

Cart Service

```
 addProductToCart(product:Product,Valuesize):Observable<any>{
 
     return this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, {product}).pipe(
      map(data =>{
         this.postId=data.id;  //able to get id of item of post      
           data["size"]=Valuesize;
          
        
       return data;
                              
  
     })
    
     )
    
  
   }
```

Product example

```
"products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Red Onepiece",
      "size": "",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
       printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
       industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an 
       unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
       make a type specimen book.",
      "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/overalls.png",
      "price": 160
    },
]
```

Development tool out put

```
 {product: {…}, id: 12, size: 'M'}
    id: 12
    product: {id: 2, name: 'Red Onepiece', size: '', description: 
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a…pe and 
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book.', imageUrl: 
   'http://localhost:4200/assets/redonepiece-r.png', …}
    size: "M"
   
Size is never added to cart
```

Response from post

```
 {
  "product": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Red Onepiece",
    "size": "",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an 
    unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
    a type specimen book.",
    "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/redonepiece-r.png",
    "price": 160
  },
  "id": 12
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the map operator in your addProductToCart call to the response you get back instead of the data you send in. You just need to modify the product before sending the POST request

```
addProductToCart(product: Product, Valuesize): Observable<any> {
  const product = { ...product, size: Valuesize };
  return this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, { product });
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, Yes I figured  out that what ever code I needed to add must come before the return,

Answer (score 0):

Hello as I stated in my comment that whatever code I needed had to come before the return.  I actually got it working after much research, which is a better sure way, along with a slight change to my model.  The model change was this.size = product.size other wise it would not show up in my view.  I used oject.defineProperty(), works perfectly for the requirements I wrote.  Here is the link for this reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty.

My updated service

```
addProductToCart(product:Product,Valuesize:string):Observable<any>{
    Object.defineProperties(product,{
        
      size:{
      value:Valuesize,
      writable: false
      }
      
    });
    return this.http.post<any>(cartUrl, {product})
    
  }
```

Hope this helps some one.
PDH